# How do i get more hard drive space?

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 12.10 with Windows 7 & I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on a 100gig partition but the biggest HD space option when I installed Ubuntu was only 30gig. How can I allocate more space for Ubuntu on that partition?

Comment: use a live-cd and use gparted to change the sizes of your diferent partitions.

Comment: you might have installed from inside windows. If you have installed Ubuntu freshly and not more customizations or updates were done then it is better to resize other partition and add it to Ubuntu partition using **easeus** software from inside windows. Its complicated to do it without data loss because easeus doesn't recognize ext4(other than ntfs) partition and if you try from inside Ubuntu you can't add(expand) Ubuntu partition unless you unmount Ubuntu paritition

Comment: Yes, I installed it from inside windows. The partition that I installed Ubuntu on is 100gig but the installation option for Ubuntu was only 30. The whole partition was empty before the installation.I have updated it & installed a few programs. I don't have any important files so I can re-install it if need be. Is there a way to choose a bigger size during installation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you were able to see an empty 100GB partition from Windows.  If that's the case, Ubuntu setup should be able to see the same 100GB partition and you should be able to allocate the entire partition to Ubuntu.

Your best option here is to run setup again, and wipe the partition during setup.  Use the manual partitioning option ("Do something else")